# Is there a way in Python to identify all possible relationships back up to a single parent

Tags: python, tree

I'm currently working through a problem within the dataset (stored as a dataframe) I have that I'm not sure how to solve for. One of the tables in the dataset shows all relationships for a given ID.  But there are multiple instances where a child of a parent will have other relationships as well as the grandchild having its own set and so on...  What I want to achieve is a single table that shows all possible matches for a given ID.

Example of Original Table

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |

Final Result

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

Is this the right way to structure the data? the true dataset has 15k rows so I think it will be a lot larger after this operation.

Cheers

I've looked into tree structures but not 100% sure if that's what's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `df` your dataframe you could try the following:

```py
def descendants(childs, source):
    descendants = set()
    stack = [source]
    while stack:
        descendant = stack.pop()
        if descendant not in childs:
            continue
        for child in childs[descendant]:
            if child != source and child not in descendants:
                stack.append(child)
                descendants.add(child)
    return descendants

childs = {parent: set(childs) for parent, childs in df.groupby("Parent")["Child"]}

df_descendants = pd.DataFrame(
    [(parent, descendants(childs, parent)) for parent in df["Parent"].unique()],
    columns=["Parent", "Descendant"]
).explode("Descendant", ignore_index=True).sort_values(["Parent", "Descendant"])
```

Or you could just use [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html):

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source="Parent", target="Child")
df_descendants = pd.DataFrame(
    [(parent, nx.descendants(G, parent)) for parent in df["Parent"].unique()],
    columns=["Parent", "Descendant"]
).explode("Descendant", ignore_index=True).sort_values(["Parent", "Descendant"])
```

Result for the sample (both alternatives):

```
   Parent Descendant
0       1          2
1       1          3
2       1          4
3       2          1
4       2          3
5       2          4
6       3          1
7       3          2
8       3          4
```

If you want to include the distance of the descendants from their ancestors then you have to switch from a DFS to a BFS (by using a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with `.appendleft` for `stack`):

```py
from collections import deque

def descendants(childs, source):
    descendants = {}
    stack = deque([(source, 0)])
    while stack:
        descendant, distance = stack.pop()
        distance += 1
        if descendant not in childs:
            continue
        for child in childs[descendant]:
            if child != source and child not in descendants:
                stack.appendleft((child, distance))
                descendants[child] = distance
    return descendants

childs = {
    parent: set(childs) for parent, childs in df.groupby("Parent")["Child"]
}

df_descendants = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (parent, descendant, distance)
        for parent in df["Parent"].unique()
        for descendant, distance in descendants(childs, parent).items()
    ],
    columns=["Parent", "Descendant", "Distance"]
).sort_values(["Parent", "Distance", "Descendant"])
```

Result for the sample:

```
   Parent  Descendant  Distance
0       1           2         1
1       1           3         1
2       1           4         2
3       2           1         1
4       2           4         1
5       2           3         2
6       3           2         1
7       3           1         2
8       3           4         2
```

Comment: Amazing, this get me the exactly what i was after, thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know if, using the df solution above, it would be possible to capture degree of separation?  i.e. in the dataset above, where ID = 1 has gone through ID = 2 to bring back ID = 4 that would show a 2 degree of separation?  But the relationship between 1 and 2 would only be 1 degree.

Comment: @thecoxinitiative Off the top of my head I don't know if there's an integrated networkx solution for that. I've edited in an adjustment of the pure Python solution that seems to do what you want.

Answer (score -2):

Original table is just a regular graph.

[image: graph]

```
graph LR;
    1-->2;
    1-->3;
    2-->1;
    2-->4;
    3-->2;
```

"shows all possible matches for a given ID": use BFS or DFS starting at ID after generating graph, and exclude starting ID.